# Is there a way to late-initialize a member variable (a class) in C++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, lazy-initialization

I am coming from the Java background. I have the following program.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class First {
    public:
    First(int someVal): a(someVal) {

    }
    int a;
};

class Second {
    public:
    First first;
    Second()  {   // The other option would be to add default value as ": first(0)"
        first = First(123);

    }
};

int main()
{
    Second second;
    std::cout << "hello" << second.first.a << std::endl;
}
```

In class `Second`, I wanted to variable `first` to remain uninitialized until I specifically initialize it in `Second()'s constructor`. Is there a way to do it? Or am I just left with 2 options?:

1. Provide a parameter-less constructor.
2. Initialize it with some default value and later re-assign the required value.

I can't initialize `first` in the initializer-list with the right value, since the value is obtained after some operation. So, the actual required value for `first` is available in `Second()` constructor only.

Comment: `first` will be initialized as soon as you instantiate a `Second`. There's no way around that. All you can do is change its value at a later stage.

Comment: Use a pointer. I Java it's all pointers, that confuses you.

Comment: @juanchopanza so you recommend going with this way:
`Second() : first(0) {
        first = First(123);
    }`

Comment: It's possible to do the calculations and use them to initialize `first` in the parameter list still.  Use a function.

Comment: @PeterSchneider True, but I want it use it as least as possible. To save myself bothering about destructor,assignment-operator and copy-constructor

Comment: I fail to see what you want to do. You don't want to initialize `first` yet in `Second`'s constructor you are initializing it anyway? Set `first` to be a pointer and set it to `NULL` or `nullptr` for C++11 in your constructor. Then at a later stage use `new First(arg)` to create a new pointer to an object of First type

Comment: So use an appropriate smart pointer type, either `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, depending on what d-tor, assignment, and copy should do.

Comment: This is _no_ place for a pointer (smart or otherwise).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MY suggestion: Use a function:

```
private: static int calculate_first(int input) {return input*5;}
explicit Second(int input) : first(calculate_first(input)) {}
```

Base classes will be initialized in the order they're declared in the class inheritance list, and then members will be initialized in the order that they're listed in the class, so the calculation *can* depend on non-static member-variables and base classes *if* they have already been initialized.

---

Alternatively:

Default constructor, then reassign:

```
explicit Second(int input) { first = input*5; }
```

Dummy value, then reassign:

```
explicit Second(int input) : first(0) { first = input*5; }
```

Use boost::optional (or [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as of C++17):

```
boost::optional<First> first;
explicit Second(int input) { first = input*5; }
```

Use the heap:

```
std::unique_ptr<First> first;
explicit Second(int input) { first.reset(new First(input*5));}
Second(const Second& r) first(new First(*(r->first))) {}
Second& operator=(const Second& r) {first.reset(new First(*(r->first)));}
```

Placement new:

```
This is tricky and not suggested 
and worse in every way than boost::optional
So sample deliberately missing.
But it is an option.
```

Comment: About the static `calculate_first` function mentioned in the first suggestion, this isn't going to work if the calculations depend on non-static member-variables or member-variables of base-class right?

Comment: @linuxeasy: Base classes will be initialized in the order they're declared in the class inheritance list, and then members will be initialized in the order that they're listed in the class, so the calculation _can_ depend on non-static member-variables and base classes _if_ they have already been initialized.

Comment: Practically, all but the first two are to be avoided.  On the other hand... I've occasionally found it useful to provide a "simplified" constructor for something like his `First`, which takes an explicit, dummy parameter to tell the constructor to do nothing (or as little as possible for a later assign to work).

Comment: Sadly it's C++20 now and we still don't have a better way to write a constructor.

Comment: @RnMss: And it never will. The fundamental problem is how composition works. These are the _theoretical_ solutions. It's possible I'm missing something, but this is never going to get "better".  The Java solution is merely syntactical sugar for the heap variant.

Comment: @MooingDuck It will be a disaster initializing non move/copy constructible members.

Comment: And yet somehow it's worked for every program in every language so far....

Answer (score 4):

Initialize `first` in the member initializer list.

It may help to perform your calculations in a helper function and use a forwarding constructor:

```
class Second {
public:
    Second() : Second(helper_function()) {}

private:
    Second(int calc): first(calc) {}
    static int helper_function() { return ...; }

    First first;
};
```

Comment: About the static helper function mentioned herein, this isn't going to work if the calculations depend on non-static member-variables or member-variables of base-class right?

Comment: @linuxeasy no, it won't. You can make it a non-static member function if you're careful about only referring to members defined before `first`.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence is the core of the problem:

> I can't initialize first in the initializer-list with the right value,
>   since the value is obtained after some operation.

You should know that what you want to do here is **not perfect programming style in Java, either**. Leaving the field with some default value and then assigning it a bit later after some calculations have been done effectively prevents it from being `final`, and consequently the class from being immutable.

In any case, your goal must be to push those calculations directly into the initialization of the member, using **private helper functions** (which may be static):

```
class Second {
private:
    First first;

    static int getInitializationData()
    {
        // complicated calculations go here...
        return result_of_calculations;
    }
public:
    Second() : first(getInitializationData()) {}
};
```

In my opinion, everything else is just a workaround and will complicate your life in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do what you said in the comments, or, you can make first a pointer to First and give it memory whenever you like, although i don't recommend this way

Answer (score 1):

One way to separate object lifetimes is to use the heap, make `first` a pointer and initialize it anytime you like:

```
class Second {
public:
    First* first;
    Second()  { 
        first = new First(123);

    }
};
```

of course, you'll probably want to use a smart pointer of some sort rather than a *raw* pointer.

Comment: well i dont think a smart pointer is required in this context, especially since its in a class he can just delete it in the dtor()

Comment: @DTSCode a `std::unique_ptr` will do exactly what a `delete` in the dtor would do *without having to write that extra code in the dtor*.  Where's the benifit of *not* doing that?

Comment: @DTSCode: Just deleting it in the destructor would give the class invalid copy semantics. You'll need [more work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) or a smart pointer (or one of the better suggestions in other answers) to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't code to explicitly initialize a member variable, the default initializer is used to initialize it.

The draft C++ standard has the following about initialization of base classes and member variables:

> **12.6 Initialization [class.init]**
>
> 1 When no initializer is specified for an object of (possibly cv-qualified) class type (or array thereof), or the initializer has the form (), the object is initialized as specified in 8.5.

And

> **12.6.1 Explicit initialization [class.expl.init]**
>
> 1 An object of class type can be initialized with a parenthesized expression-list, where the expression-list is construed as an argument list for a constructor that is called to initialize the object. Alternatively, a single assignment-expression can be specified as an initializer using the = form of initialization. Either direct-initialization semantics or copy-initialization semantics apply; see 8.5.