# object with constructor as a class member c++

Tags: c++, object, header-files, eigen

I have a Data class that contains a `VectorXf` object from the Eigen Template Library. This `vector` object has a constructor that accepts an `int` defining how much memory to allocate. However, this number is not known at compile time.

Anyway, what I am trying to do is declare the VectorXf object in my Data class header file, then construct that VectorXf object during construction of my Data object. I'm new to c++, so I am a little confused on how to do this. I keep getting an error that says `undefined reference to Data::vector(int)` What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Header file `Data.h` for my Data class:

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

class Data
{
    public:
        Data(string file);
        virtual ~Data();
        void readFile(string file);

    private:
        VectorXf vector(int n);

};

#endif // DATA_H
```

So, as you can see from the header file above, a `data` object contains a vector object that takes an integer as a parameter.

Here is the `Data.cpp` file:

```
#include "Data.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Eigen\Eigen>
#include<fstream>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;


Data::Data(string file)
{
    readFile(file);

}

void Data :: readFile(string file){

    int n = ... // read file length using fstream
    vector(n); //construct the VectorXd object that was declared in Data.h

}   

Data::~Data()
{
    //dtor
}
```

For clarity, what needs to happen in my main function:

```
   Data data("myfile.txt")
```

which creates a `Data` object. Then a file length is read since the Data constructor calls `readFile()`, which determines the appropriate length to construct the `VectorXf` object that is a `Data` class member. What is the proper way of referring to and constructing my class member objects - `VectorXf vector` in this case.

Comment: Sorry to dupe hammer your question with this link. I know you didn't specifically ask that. But however, the answers in the duplicate should give you every information necessary to get your code working.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the link, I can use the information there to solve my problem in an ALTERNATIVE way. However, I am not seeing an answer to my question. I am not passing the `int n` parameter through the constructor of the `data` object. Therefore I can not use the member initialization list. I require a method to be called before that `int n` can even be determined. So, is this not possible?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you mean to say that I must pass `n` through the constructor so that I can use member initialization? If that is true, then I would have to read the file to determine the length before I even create my Data object. I am trying to implement the file read within the Data class THEN construct the member `VectorXf` object

Comment: found my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702484/is-there-a-way-to-late-initialize-a-member-variable-a-class-in-c

Comment: Well, I've reopened your question (maybe to let it get closed as a dupe of the question you've been researching yourself).